# Why does Bitbake build get stucked during parsing of receipts when running in gitlab-ci?

Tags: docker, build, gitlab, gitlab-ci, bitbake

I am running a `bitbake` (version 1.44) build inside a docker container inside gitlab-ci. But the build get stucket at the beginning of parsing `recipes...`. Even after several hours of waiting I see no process.

Nevertheless the build runs inside the container on my local machine pretty fine.

**Why does Bitbake build get stucked during parsing of receipts when running in gitlab-ci?**

In earlier versions pf Bitbake there was a `-i` option to drop interactive mode. I tried to use this option to solve the problem but it did not help.